# Query optimization with nested select

Tags: sql

I have a table `products` and a Table `translations`. I have `n` translations for each product, but there is always at least a default translation (`LangID = 0`).

What I want to do is a "search-query" for a string a user entered. If there is a translation in the language which the users uses (let's say `LangID = 1`) I want only to search translations for this language (and also NOT in the default one), but if there is no translation in the desired language I want to search in the default translation. So basically the default translation is just a fallback.

What I came up with:

```
SELECT * FROM products p JOIN translations t ON p.ID = t.ProductID 
WHERE (t.LangID = 1 OR (t.LangID = 0 AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT id FROM translations t2 WHERE t2.ProductID = p.ID AND t2.LangID = 1))
      AND t.Translation LIKE "Foo%" `
```

Is this the best way to go or is it possible to do this without the nested-select? Or is there a far better (performance wise) query / approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it like this but it is unclear whether the execution plan is good or erratically bad. The combination of `OR` and `EXISTS` does not reliably result in a good plan.

It is safer and faster to just join twice:

```
select *
from products p
left join translations t1 on t1.langid = 1 and ...
left join translations t0 on t1.langid is null and t0.langid = 0 and ...
```

You then use the values of `t1` if they exist. If not you use the values of `t0`. The predicate `t1.langid is null` is optional but it allows SQL Server (hopefully) to skip the second join in case the first one succeeds. I have seen this pattern work but it's not safe to assume that it always does.

This results in a reliable and simple plan.

Comment: Thanks this is the best answer for me. The complete query I wrote: `select p.Id, COALESCE(t1.Translation, t0.Translation) from product p 
left join translations t1 on t1.ProductId = p.Id and t1.LanguageId = 1
left join translations t0 on t0.ProductId = p.Id and t1.LanguageId IS NULL and t0.LanguageId = 0
where t1.Translation like 'Foo%' or t0.Translation like 'Foo%`.

Answer (score 1):

```
with t as (
SELECT * FROM products p JOIN translations t ON p.ID = t.ProductID 
WHERE t.LangID = 1 AND t.Translation LIKE "Foo%")
select * from t
union all
SELECT * FROM products p, translations t 
 where (select count(*) from t) = 0
   and p.ID = t.ProductID 
   and t.LangID = 0 AND t.Translation LIKE "Foo%"';
```

It's an Oracle syntax, **t** is just a subquery (WITH lets you give names to subqueries)

If the process of calculating **t** is complex this query may be faster

P.S. Your database may not use short-cut evaluation for WHERE conditions. Need to test (actually Oracle doesn't guarantee its usage, but Oracle optimizer is smart enough, so it worked in my case)